# Nexus 4 MTP not showing on Device Manager

Tags: windows, mtp

When I disable USB Debugging on the Nexus 4 and connect it to my Windows 7 x64 Ultimate, a "Nexus 4" shows up in "My Computer" and the device is also listed on "Device Manager", under "Portable Devices" It all works as it is meant to.

However, as soon as I enable USB Debugging, I am asked to install drivers for "ADB Interface" which I do and then shows as working. This however removes the "Nexus 4" from "My Computer" and also there is nothing under "Device Manager", "Portable Devices"

Despite the driver being correctly installed for ADB Interface, when I do "adb devices" no devices is listed.

I have tried uninstalling and deleting the drivers over and over with no success. I have tried the Naked Drivers 0.72 and also the latest ones from the SDK.

The same USB cable, Nexus 4 and drivers all work perfectly on other Windows 7 x64 devices I have tested on. It even worked on VMWare through the same USB port it didn't work on the host!

There is something wrong with my Windows 7. I connected a USB device "AC309N" and my Windows did not install the driver automatically. When I connected the same device to my laptop running the same Windows 7 version, it automatically installed the driver. This leads me to believe something relating to USB/Plug 'n Play is not fully functioning.

Really want to avoid a reinstall!

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: On the computer that fails to install the drivers properly, do you see any devices at all with a yellow exclamation mark in the device manager?  If so you can go into the properties for the device and reinstall them which should hopefully get you the right drivers installed. I have actually seen devices without proper installers use this as their install method as Windows 7 seemingly decided to do away with the "ask the user for drivers" wizard. Without the proper drivers preinstalled or available on Windows Update it just installs a dummy "failed" driver...

Comment: I do not see the "Nexus 4" aka MTP device anywhere on the Device Manager list. I have even enabled "Show hidden devices"

Comment: As soon as I disable USB Debugging, the "Nexus 4" shows up on the Device Manager" list and works as intended. This is not normal as it works perfectly on other Window 7 devices.

Comment: Do you see *any* devices with a yellow exclamation mark? Not necessarily named Nexus. Also have you tried unplugging the Nexus, enabling USB debugging and plugging the nexus in again?

Comment: I do not see ANY additional devices listed anywhere else, nothing under Unknown or Other. No device has the yellow exclamation mark on list. I have tried enabling USB Debugging before plugging into the PC, I have also tried enabling it after plugging into the PC. To put it simply, when connected the Nexus 4, only device detected by device manager is "Google Nexus ADB Interface" If USB Debugging is disabled, the PC makes that hardware connected sound and "Nexus 4" appears under "Portable Devices"

Comment: This sounds very odd and I can understand your frustration with this. The last two things I can suggest without actually having the fault myself is to go into the 'Nexus ADB Interface' and select the option to reinstall the drivers and see if that triggers anything otherwise on the top icon bar in Device Manager one of the icons is "Scan for new plug and play hardware" (should be a little computer icon) and this may trigger a driver installation wizard for you.

Comment: I have already tried this many times without success. I am going to reinstall Windows tomorrow, too much time has already been spent on this issue. I really appreciate all your help Mokubai, thank you very much.

Comment: I have the same problem exactly. if you managed to solve this, Please let us know here. My case is a nexus 4 that can be seen in USB debugging only (as android original adb interface), but without the usb debugging on the device, its invisable (no MTP and no nothing) - Using XP

Answer (score 0):

In Device Manager :

UpdateDriver->Manuel Install->Search on my computer->Select from installed driver list -> then select the one with the word usb in it (not MTP).